# UnboundLocalError at /accounts/register/

Tags: python, django

hi i was trying to check if a user with a same number is in my database , i show a error that this number is exists from before
but ...
UnboundLocalError at /accounts/register/

[forms.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bufBO.png)

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDvNJ.png)

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTFCB.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please post the relevant code instead of images. Check  [why not to upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.